# Plotting the determinant of a matrix over a range of values

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to plot a function which will tell me the value of determinant of a given input.

```
x = 0:0.1:1
y = det([(cos(x)/x)^2,2*(cos(x)/x),2*(cos(x)/x);2*(cos(x)/x),8,8;2*(cos(x)/x),8,12])
figure
plot(x,y)
```

And here is what I got.

[image]

I have realized that there is only one y value but I do not know why. How do I make MATLAB show the determinant value for all `x` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to achieve something like this:

```
 x = linspace(0,1);
for i = 1:numel(x)
y(i) = det([(cos(x(i))/x(i))^2,2*(cos(x(i))/x(i)),2*(cos(x(i))/x(i));2*(cos(x(i))/x(i)),8,8;2*(cos(x(i))/x(i)),8,12]);
end
plot(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant) would've told you: the determinant of a matrix is a single number. Hence, you only have one `y` value, and thus can plot only one point.

I presume you're looking for the determinant at each of your `x` values, in that case, use a `for` loop on your `y` to calculate each determinant instead of only one. Trying to calculate a sort-of 3D matrix this way (well, a 2D matrix over a range of `x` values, basically 3D) doesn't work. MATLAB'll use the last value of `x` and ignore the rest to calculate your *3*-by-*3* matrix, and from that it'll calculate the determinant, i.e. a single number.

Comment: With a for loop I am obtaining more values but the graph is still empty do You have any idea why?

Comment: @roffensive edit the question to show the code with for loop so that we can take a look

Comment: @roffensive probably because your `for` loop is wrong. As I am not clairvoyant, I can't say more until you actually show the code which is faulty. Besides, this is about as basic a `for` loop you can get, so if you can't write that correctly, I strongly suggest you to take a look at [the tutorial by The MathWorks themselves](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html)